# How to input bytes from read-host in powershell

Tags: powershell, byte

So i have this code `[byte[]] $key = read-Host` and I want to know proper syntax for input via the read-host. Its for password encryption key for a secure password safe.

Comment: Maybe `[byte[]] $key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((read-Host -AsSecureString))`?

Answer (score 0):

`Read-Host` reads a string. You can convert it to bytes (but not as a cast), but it sounds like what you want is something that reads input as bytes and validates it. It's unclear if you want to enter decimal, hexadecimal, octal, etc.

The validation would have to come after the user entered the data, for example if you wanted hex:

```
do {
    $in = Read-Host
} while ($in -notmatch '^(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2})+$')
```

It just keeps asking until the string is hex bytes. With more information we could better answer your question.

Comment: OK so i want a string of numbers that i can use as a key for the Convert From-Secure String -key operator. i have seen the way to do it in script as (1,2,3,4,5,6) and want that as the way the user inputs. ie. user inputs matches the way the program reads the above number set